# Python - How to check a data format in a Pandas DataFrame column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, format

I have a PD DataFrame and want to test 1)if a column contains a value and 2)if values in another column are in a format of positive percent decimal numbers?

I test if an Id value is not in the DF like this: `assert "C50" not in metrics_df["id"].tolist()`.

How can I check that the values in a `metric_1` column are in the right format of percent decimal (0.05; 0.238)? The only valid value of

```
    df = self.spark.createDataFrame(
        [('A10', -0.35, '2020-01-04'),
         ('A20', -0.20, '2017-05-01'),
         ('B30', 0.59, '2018-02-08'),
         ],
        ['id', 'metric_1', 'transaction_date']
    )
```

Comment: _How can I check that the values in a metric_1 column are in the right format of percent decimal (0.05; 0.238)_: Do you want them to be in that interval or simply a positive number between 0 and 1. And what would you like to do with the values that do not meet the condition? remove them from data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, this could help you:

```
assert (box_raw["metric_1"] < 1).all() and (box_raw["metric_1"] > 0).all()
```